# Is Transit visa needed for Reykjavik while traveling to India from USA (round trip)

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, indian-citizens, paperwork

Is Transit visa needed for Reykjavik while traveling to India from USA. I hold Indian passport and valid USA visa. My layover in Reykjavik is for 6.30 hours 1 way and other way is 2.30 hours. Has anyone travel recently in similar situation without applying for any transit visa for Reykjavik, Iceland. I tried calling Embassy but no one answered the call and no response so far for my email sent.

Answer (score 0):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Visa required, **except** for passengers arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight on the same calendar day to a third country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport, and have documents required for the next destination.

So if the trip is in a single booking, you don't need a visa

Comment: That's assuming his next layover is not in the Schengen area. (There must be _some_ next layover since there are no direct flights between Iceland and India). And there are very few destinations east of Keflavik that are _not_ in Schengen, basically only the UK or Ireland. No flights to Moscow, Istanbul, Dubai, Doha, or Abu Dhabi either.

Comment: (Hmm, it seems my information was outdated. WOW now has a route to New Delhi).

Comment: That would be one hell of a flight on a LCC.